# Error using include sys/resource.h with Windows 10 C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS code on macOS for a while and switched to windows 10, I tried running a code from my mac but it's giving me this error that I don't get using mac. I installed LLVM not sure if it would help.

```
#Include <sys/resource.h>
```

My compiler path currently is set to:

```
"compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
```

Can I use the usual commands gcc/g++ this way?

I am new to windows and not sure how to configure things in a clean ay. Thanks.

Comment: What error? Also it should be `#include`, lower-case.

Comment: It's possible that `sys/resource.h` is a BSD thing that doesn't exist in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys/resource.h` is a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) header file, that's why your system is not able to find it anywhere on windows.

If you still want to use it then you can either either use a virtual machine or install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) on your system.